# Django ModelForm, create many at once

Tags: django, select, modelform

This may sound a bit weird.

I have a list of objects, called Items. For each of these I want to be able to create another object called Main. Main has a foreignkey to Item.

Creating a ModelForm of Main gives me the option to chose one Item for the foreignkey field.

What i want is something like being able to select multiple values in the foreignkey field of the modelform, and then when handling the form data, create one Main object for each selection.

I've tried simply overriding the field to ModelMultipleChoiceField, but I can't seem to find a way to handle it when submitting data. I cannot find a method to retrieve all the selected values, so I can start the loop, that is: I want to fetch the selected values into a list before looping. Something like:

```
form = Form(request.POST)
list = form.fields['foreignkey'].values()

for l in list:
    form.fields['foreignkey'] = l
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        ...
    ...
```

Excepts, the values() method do not exist, so...

Hope this makes sense... Any ideas?

Comment: I am not sure, but are you looking for formsets?

Comment: I'll have a look at formsets and see what turns up

Comment: It seems formsets are about making multiple forms. What I want is one form, that'll make several objects. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 0):

1. **Add a new ModelMultipleChoiceField**, say `multiple_items`, rather than overriding the FK's default field,
2. **Override `form.save()`**, to create a Main for each `self.cleaned_data['multiple_items']`

Comment: That looks like something that might work... I'll give it a go